# Angular Google API get geolocation and address details

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am trying to make my own custom widget using Google API AutocompleteService. I am able to get the predictions but how do I get the address details such as split of address by city, region, street etc as well as the geolocation? Currently I get a the street address but it doesn't split it I just get offset array and no postcode. Here is my code so far, thanks in advance!

```
private autocompleteService: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  }
  getAutocompletePredictions(ev): void {
    this.presentPopover(ev);
    const request = {
      input: '15 smith Road',
      fields: ["address_components", "adr_address", "geometry", "name"],
      types: ['geocode'],
      componentRestrictions: { country: 'au' }
    };

    this.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(request, (predictions, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log(predictions);
        this.records = predictions;
      } else {
        console.error(`Error retrieving autocomplete predictions: ${status}`);
      }
    });
  }

  getPlaceDetails(placeId: string): void {
    // when a record is selected I can pass the placeId here. what do I do then?
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With good direction from @MrUpsidown, here is the code that worked for me:

Component

```
records:any[];
sessionToken: any;
  private autocompleteService: any;
  private placesService:any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div')); // Create a dummy map
    this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    this.sessionToken = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken();
  }
  getAutocompletePredictions(ev): void {
    this.presentPopover(ev);
    const request = {
      input: '15 Smith Road',
      fields: ["address_components", "adr_address", "geometry", "name"],
      types: ['geocode'],
      componentRestrictions: { country: 'au' },
      sessionToken: this.sessionToken
    };

    this.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(request, (predictions, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log(predictions);
        this.records = predictions;
      } else {
        console.error(`Error retrieving autocomplete predictions: ${status}`);
      }
    });
  }

 

  getPlaceDetails(placeId: string): void {
    console.log("Place Id",placeId);
    const request = {
      placeId: placeId,
      fields: ["address_components", "adr_address", "geometry", "name"],
      sessionToken: this.sessionToken // Add session token
    };

    this.placesService.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log('Place', place);
      } else {
        console.error(`Error retrieving place details: ${status}`);
      }
    });
  }
```

HTML: I have widget that lists the results:

```
    <ion-list class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let record of records" lines="full"  (click)="getPlaceDetails(record.place_id)"  button="true">    
          <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
            {{record.description}}
          </ion-label>          
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: You can remove `"address_components", "adr_address"` from the fields in the `getPlacePredictions()` because as I said, these fields are not taken into account in these requests.

Answer (score 1):

`address_components` is only available via a Place Details request. You cannot use this field in your Autocomplete request. The same goes for the `adr_address` field btw.

See the [PlaceResult interface documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult).

*what do I do then?*

You should do a [Place Details request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) and specify the `address_components` field in there.

Note that you should also use [session tokens](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#session_tokens) in both requests. If you do so, the documentation specifies that:

> *You can use the same session token to make a single Place Details request on the place that results from a call to `AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions()`. In this case, the autocomplete request is combined with the Place Details request, and the call is charged as a regular Place Details request. There is no charge for the autocomplete request.*

If you don't use session tokens, you will get billed for both requests.

**Edit:**

*Maybe I reading wrong but the code requires to pass a map service ...*

As I commented, you need to pass either a map instance, or an HTML DIV element. It is not mandatory to display places details on a map. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService).

Something like that would work:

```
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
```

As it sounds you don't want to display a map, you should also read the [Places API policies](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/policies) and adhere to it (you need to display a Google logo and attributions).

Comment: thanks is there a way to do this without loading a map into the html?

Comment: Why not? You haven't created a map in the code you shared as far as I can tell. Your code mentions `// when a record is selected I can pass the placeId here` so just do a place details request with the place id. I have even linked to the docs in my answer.

Comment: Maybe I reading wrong but the code requires to pass a map service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)? In any case I found the solution using geocode API instead, thanks for your help!  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id

Comment: And thanks for the advice on the session token I will certainly include that in the code!

Comment: never mind just realised geocode API you are charged even for the first 100,000

Comment: *the code requires to pass a map service* - no, if you check the docs, it either requires a map instance, or an HTML DIV element. See my updated answer.